# ER_PARSE_ERROR in Nest js

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, nestjs

Hello i have problem with relations in NestJS.

I was trying to get user with relation named club like that:

```
async findOne(id: number): Promise<User> {
  return this.userRepository.findOne({
    where: { id: id },
    relations: ['club'],
  });
}
```

And that throws this error:

```
ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `User`.`id` = 1) `distinct Alias`  ORDER BY `User_id` ASC LIMIT 1' at line 1
```

I think my entites look correct, can it be problem with MariaDB?

There is my User entity:

```
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;
  @Column()
  @Unique('email_unique', ['email'])
  email: string;
  @Column()
  @Unique('username_unique', ['username'])
  username: string;
  @Column()
  password: string;
  @Column({ type: 'boolean' })
  active = false;
  @Column()
  activationToken: string;
  @OneToOne(() => Club, (club) => club.user)
  club: Club;
}
```

And Club entity:

```
@Entity()
export class Club {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;
  @ManyToOne(() => League)
  league: League;
  @OneToOne(() => User, (user) => user.club)
  user: User;
  @Column()
  name: string;
  @Column()
  location: string;
  @OneToMany(() => Player, (player) => player.club)
  players: Player[];
}
```

Comment: Chech what sql statement your js code generates. My guess is that is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `JoinColumn` annotation - it could be the reason for the erroneous generated sql. Try defining the `JoinColumn` on the owning side, e.g.

```
export class User {
  // ...
  @OneToOne(() => Club, (club) => club.user)
  @JoinColumn()
  club: Club;
}
```